# Javascript - perform operation vertically and horizontally with dynamic text input

Tags: javascript, php, html

need help i am working with some text inputs here that are dynamic depending on how many the user enter. what i wanted to do is to compute the text inputs automatically after user input value using onkeyup javascript.
here the php and html code:

```
<?Php

$x = 10;
$i = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++){
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply()' id='tb1'>";
    echo "x";
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply()' id='tb2'>";
    echo "=";
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply()' id='tb3'>";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>

total:<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply()' id='tb4'>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
<script>
    function multiply(){
        var textbox1 = document.getElementById('tb1').value;
        var textbox2 = document.getElementById('tb2').value;
        var result = parseFloat(textbox1) * parseFloat(textbox2);
        if(!isNaN(result))
        {
            document.getElementById('tb3').value = result;
        }
    }
</script>
```

now, the first row of text inputs works fine but the remaining text inputs doesn't I know i'm missing something here and i can't figure it out, how can 
i compute horizontally those values from tb1 and tb2 then display it on tb3
and compute vertically all the values of tb3 and display it in tb4. any help is much appreciated.TIA

Comment: Here's where I would start: change your rendered HTML so that each row is output within a `<div>` or some kind of container. Then, instead of using IDs, put a class name on the inputs, such as "number1", "number2", and "answer". Then, in the  `multiply` function, use the much more powerful `document.querySelectorAll` to traverse up from the input that triggered the event to the container, and then using this function again, find each child by class name ("number1", "number2", etc.). Then you can perform the rest of your calculate and update. This eliminates all the hard-coded IDs.

Comment: Could this be because you are duplicating `ID`'s... You might want to swap the `ID's` for a `class` and iterate the `class` group.

Comment: sir **Cᴏʀʏ** theres someting i didn't understand with your answer,how can i declare each div as rows? do you mean i need to put css on it?? but still tanks for the response sir.

Answer (score 0):

Well all rows contain elements with same ids. So row 1 will contain elements with ids: tb1, tb2, tb3. Row 2 will also contain elements with ids tb1, tb2 and tb3.

The id of each element on a page needs to be unique. You can make the ids unique by appending the row number to the id. For example:

```
<?php

$x = 10;
$i = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++){
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply(" . $i . ")' id='tb" . $i . "-1'>";
    echo "x";
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply(" . $i . ")' id='tb" . $i . "-2'>";
    echo "=";
    echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='multiply(" . $i . ")' id='tb" . $i . "-3'>";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>

Total: <input type='text' id='tb4'> <input type='button' onclick='CalculateSum()' title='Calculate Sum'>
```

Your JavaScript code will then look as follows:

```
<script>
    function multiply(row) {
        var textbox1 = document.getElementById('tb' + row + '-1').value;
        var textbox2 = document.getElementById('tb' + row + '-2').value;
        var result = parseFloat(textbox1) * parseFloat(textbox2);
        if(!isNaN(result))
        {
            document.getElementById('tb' + row + '-3').value = result;
        }
    }

    function CalculateSum() {
        let total = 0;
        for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            total += document.getElementById('tb' + i + '-3').value;
        }
        document.getElementById('tb4').value = total; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: one last question sir @Nadir how can i get the total of tb3 and display it in tb4